# Copy any kind of file to clipboard with xclip

Tags: file-copy, clipboard, ranger, xclip

So, I want to be able to copy any kind of file to an X clipboard with a shell script (mostly as a means to copy files in ranger, to gui applications).
So far i have this script:

```
TYPE=$(file -b --mime-type "$1")
xclip "$1" -selection clipboard -t "$TYPE"
```

Which, does work to an extent, however this only assigns one mime type to the clipboard, and for example if the, file is a jpeg for example then most applications wont let me paste it, if i manually copy the jpeg as a png then some applications let me paste it.
And if i have plain text files, it just grabs the content no the **file itself**.
How do i create a generic script taht can copy the files themselves to the clipboard, and set all the acceptable mime types?